# Labeling nodes with letters but removing last letter using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, sql, style, nodes

I want to label nodes of my polygon with upper letters. I got to the point where I am able to label them with the right style. What I still need to do is to dismiss the final letter because it overlays the first letter, see the following screenshot where you can see that Q (the last label) overlays A (the first label):

[image]

Here is my expression :

```
CASE WHEN @geometry_part_num <27 THEN upper(char( @geometry_part_num-1+97)) WHEN @geometry_part_num <677 THEN concat(upper(char( to_int( (@geometry_part_num-1)/26 + 96))) , upper(char( to_int((@geometry_part_num-1)%26 + 96)))) END
```

Comment: Why do you have two points in the same vertex?

Comment: i think every polygon behave like this ... i mean closing polygons implies having start and end points overlapping ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the benefit of readers, it is not really a label, but rather a font marker.

To get access to the polygon vertices, we must use `nodes_to_points`, which accepts a geometry. The second parameters instructs the function to ignore repeating vertices. As it is `false` by default (i.e. do consider all vertices), the 1st and the last points are displayed. Set it to `true` to remove them

[image]